# How to group values by timestamp

Tags: arrays, mongodb, group-by, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

For every entity in database I have array of timestamps with prices, I want to group them by timestamp and get average price for that timestamp.

I am currently using mongoose, and I tried various functions for grouping by, but I did not find solution to group by every element.

```
{ 
 _id : "52b632a9e4f2ba13c82ccd23", 
 history-dates : [2019-10-1, 2019-10-2, 2019-10-3, 2019-10-4]
 history-prices : [1000.0, 2000.0, 500.0, 1500.0]
}, 

{ 
 _id : "52b632a9e4f2ba13c82ccd23", 
 history-dates : [2019-10-1, 2019-10-2, 2019-10-3, 2019-10-4]
 history-prices : [2000.0, 3000.0, 1500.0, 2500.0]
}
```

I want to have result like:

```
date: 2019-10-1
avgPrice : 1500.0
```

How can I achieve this and thanks in advance.

Comment: That's really not a great structure. I strongly suggest you rethink that and change it. Also, why should the result be `1500.0`? From the best I can follow from the data in the question, the desired result for that date should be `3000.0`. And of course `2019-10-1` would not be a valid value for a MongoDB document. `"2019-10-1"` on the other hand, or an actual BSON Date would be valid. I would strongly suggest showing actual documents if you need a solution, since your "approximation" at current might be conveying the wrong message.

Comment: I want to track prices of some objects every day, so I can plot price change over time,

Comment: That's not what I said. Perhaps get someone to translate for you if needed. Regardless of what you "want to do", the simple facts are that using matching array indexes in separated arrays is a really bad way to do that. On the other hand `[{ "date": "2019-10-1", "price": 1000.0 },{ "date": "2019-10-2", "price": 2000.0 }]` is a lot more reasonable ( and basically what any solution on the current data would need to transform to as an intermediate stage ), but again may not be the best option depending on what your actual usage may be. But multiple arrays tied implicitly by index is pretty bad.

Comment: Ou, actually my first solution was implemented in that way. I can return it, but again how should query look so I can get the desired result.

Comment: If the previous structure was as @NeilLunn suggested, I would back that as well because then you would avoid unwinding on two array fields as a first and other caveats of having transformation indexed data points (as mentioned). For the solution for this structure you could be looking at unwinding the array field & then group-averaging. [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) [$avg](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Neil pointed out that you should change the document structure a little bit

So introduce a field `historicalPrices` with `array` type having structure as : `[{ date: "2019-10-1", price: 1000.0 }]`

Then you can apply following query to get the average price grouped by date

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "historicalPrices" },
  { $group: { 
      "_id": "$historicalPrices.date",
      avgPrice:{ $avg: "$historicalPrices.price" }
      } 
  }
])
//Result: [{ _id: "2019-10-01", avgPrice: 1500.0 }, ....]
```

Know more about [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/index.html), [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html), [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), [$avg](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/)

Comment: @andrija-novakovic Let me know if this worked out for you or not. Upvote and accept answer if it does.